# Excel: If date in cell is three days less than today display other column in same row in other cell

Tags: excel-formula, formula, xls

I'm trying to get the following formula to work, however I think I have it all wrong!

```
=IF(=A2*'DACH Idents'!B$<=TODAY,'Deletelist'!B1='DACH Idents'!C$,""())
```

I'm trying to populate worksheet "Deletelist" column B with strings from worksheet "DACH Idents" column C if the matching row date from "DACH Idents" column B is older than 3 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this in `Datelist` cell `C2`:

```
=IF((TODAY()-'DACH Idents'!B1)>3, 'DACH Idents'!C1, "")
```

It will return an empty string if the date is not older than 3 days.

Comment: Thanks, this works great, however I need to apply it to every row in columns B & C in worksheet "DACH Idents" and display in same column seperate rows "Delete List"

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you need to apply same formula to a number of rows in Datelist sheet. If so, please check out https://youtu.be/HOp4sB4yOH4?t=1m11s regarding copying formulas in Excel. It is simple )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
=IF('DACH Idents'!B2<DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())-3),'DACH Idents'!C2,0)
```

If the day is not older than 3 days, it should display a zero, and you could change it with anything you need